# JQuery click function is not working

Tags: jquery

I've seen this question before but all the answers I saw do not apply to my particular problem.  Most of the ones I've seen were caused by the click not being used in a document ready function.  All of the stuff in setup_calenders and disable_items is happening but no alert pops up when the checkbox is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(setup)

function setup() {
$("id_Clearance").click(enable_clearance);
$("id_Paperwork").click(enable_paperwork);
$("id_AVSupport").click(enable_support);
setup_calendars();
disable_items();
}

function enable_paperwork()
{
alert("clicked");
}
```

Comment: Use .on() to avoid this kin of problem.

Comment: That won't help in this case.  `click() is a shortcut for .bind("click", handler), as well as for .on("click", handler) as of jQuery 1.7`.  http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: for .on("click",handler), not for .on("click",selector,handler)

Comment: Right, and using delegated events like that helps a lot if you are updating/replacing the elements on the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the `#` signs that indicate that a selector should match an element ID:

```
$("#id_Clearance").click(enable_clearance);
$("#id_Paperwork").click(enable_paperwork);
$("#id_AVSupport").click(enable_support);
```

Comment: I did there's was some kind of block setup that made me wait to accept :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
function setup() {
  $("#id_Clearance").click(enable_clearance);
  $("#id_Paperwork").click(enable_paperwork);
  $("#id_AVSupport").click(enable_support);
  setup_calendars();
  disable_items();
}
```

You need to include a # before an element's id to select for id.  Just a name like that looks for a tag.  eg:

```
<id_Clearance/>
```

jQuery has great documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong as I don't have your html source, but it looks like you might not have the correct selectors for IDs.

Currently, you're doing this:

```
$("id_Clearance").click(enable_clearance);
$("id_Paperwork").click(enable_paperwork);
$("id_AVSupport").click(enable_support);
```

If those are indeed supposed to be ids of elements on the page, you'll want to change it to this:

```
$("#id_Clearance").click(enable_clearance);
$("#id_Paperwork").click(enable_paperwork);
$("#id_AVSupport").click(enable_support);
```

Notice the # at the start of the selectors.  That's what is used to select an id.